# read xml to a sourcestream in aleri streaming

Tags: complex-event-processing

How to read xml file to a stream in aleri. How i can create data model explorer in aleri for the xml which has nested elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can import a flat XML file using one of the built in data connectors, using sp_upload/sp_convert or sp_playback. The file needs to be in the following format:

```
<StreamName column1="value" column2="value" />
```

(The stream name does not have to match if you're using a data connector.)

Where there are nested elements it's harder. You'll either need to push the file in as a text file and reconstruct it in the model or write an adapter. In both cases you'll need to think about how you can represent the nested elements in a flat table structure.